# .local domain and iOS/OSX

Tags: ios

Hello I'm working with an hardware team to a really nice device that we can connect through with an iOS application. Currently we are using an ip address to perform calls on this device and it is working perfectly. Since we read about the new ATS specifics by Apple, we are trying to move the connection to a `.local` domain instead of using an IP address, so that we can configure domains exceptions in the `App Transport Security Settings`. We are experiencing a lot of problems trying to connect to the .local domains from the App... it seems that the DNS is never resolved. Are there any known bug related to .local domain? I seen some very old bugs... but nothing related to iOS 10/9. 
Note: Currently to connect to the device we have to put the device in Access Point mode and from iOS settings we choose it as "wi-fi" router.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [Zero configuration networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking), specifically [DNS Service Discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking#DNS-based_service_discovery), an industry standard that Apple markets as [Bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/). That's what allows a device to list its services for DNS discovery through the `.local` top-level domain.

["Publication: An Example"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Articles/NetServicesArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001074-98854) in Apple's Bonjour guide is a good place to start for understanding what you'd need to do to implement this as a hardware vendor.